# ctrl.$parsers.unshift throws undefined

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

i´m building an custom Directive to Match two input Fields.
So using `ctrl.$parsers.unshift` throws me an error `Cannot read property 'unshift' of undefined`. Can´t figure out what´s going wrong.
I´m using Angular Material Input Fields, by the way.

```
<md-input-container>
  <label>E-Mail</label>
  <input required type="email" name="clientEmail" ng-model="user.clientEmail"
         minlength="10" maxlength="100" ng-pattern="/^.+@.+\..+$/" />
  <div ng-messages="registerForm.clientEmail.$error" role="alert">
    <div ng-message-exp="['required', 'minlength', 'maxlength', 'pattern']">
      Your email must be between 10 and 100 characters long and look like an e-mail address.
    </div>
  </div>
</md-input-container>

<md-input-container>
  <label>E-Mail wiederholen</label>
  <input required type="email" name="clientEmailconfirm" ng-model="user.clientEmailconfirm"
  minlength="10" maxlength="100" ng-pattern="/^.+@.+\..+$/" field-match="{{user.clientEmail}}" />
  <div ng-messages="registerForm.clientEmailconfirm.$error" role="alert">
    <div ng-message-exp="['required', 'minlength', 'maxlength', 'pattern']">
      Your email must be between 10 and 100 characters long and look like an e-mail address.
    </div>
    <div ng-message="fieldMatch">E-Mail do not Match...</div>
  </div>
</md-input-container>
```

Directive:

```
angular.module('fieldmatcher', []);
app.directive('fieldMatch', ['$rootScope', '$compile', '$parse', function($rootScope, $compile, $parse) {
  return {
    require: ['ngModel'],
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
      ctrl.$parsers.unshift(validate);
      ctrl.$formatters.push(validate);

      var validate = function(viewValue) {
        var comparisonModel = attr.fieldMatch;

        if (!viewValue || !comparisonModel) {
          ctrl.$setValidity('fieldMatch', true);
        }

        ctrl.$setValidity('fieldMatch', (viewValue === comparisonModel));
        return viewValue;
      };

      attr.$observe('fieldMatch', function(comparisonModel) {
        return validate(ctrl.$viewValue);
      });
    }
  }
}]);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your example the parameter `ctrl` of the link function is an array with a single controller element.

This is because you used an array value for the `require` attribute.

See the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-link-) for the `ctrl` parameter:

> The exact value depends on the directive's require property:
>    1. no controller(s) required: the directive's own controller, or undefined if it doesn't have one
>    2. string: the controller instance
>    3. array: array of controller instances

So simply change to `require: 'ngModel',`.

And define the `var validate = function(...` before you put the variable into the parsers and formatters array.

Comment: Hi wero, ok got it. changed ['ngModel'] to 'ngModel' and now it works, thanks for your explanation.